# Sending a message to my XPage from Java

Tags: java, xpages

In my xpages application I am accessing some web services. I would like to send a message to the user in case a web service comes with an certain response.

For example a 9000 host return code would indicate that the service has timed out.

How can I display this in the UI?

This is what I came up with:

```
FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.addMessage(null, new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "9000 response", ""));
```

and I would display it via a Display Errors / messages control:

```
<xp:messages id="messages1" showSummary="true" showDetail="true"></xp:messages>
```

Can some one explain me which process I should follow?

Comment: Looks OK. Did you try? Does it work? In general you put your Java in a managed bean. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: And ensure the errors control is in the refresh area for that partial refresh. Also, this will only work if the partial refresh timeout is longer than the time it takes the web services to time out.

Comment: ooops! I missed that one. I also added globalOnly="true", not sure what difference that makes.